# How to say "famous quote" in Japanese?

Tags: word-requests

Just like the title stated, I'm wondering how Japanese say quote or famous quote, since 見積もり isn't the right translation for that meaning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most commonly, we would use:

・「名言{めいげん}」 or　「偉人{いじん}の名言」

・「有名{ゆうめい}な引用」 or「[Name] からの引用{いんよう}」

「見積{みつ}もり」 is way off.  It is used only in business for "quoting" a price.